# Пайтон работа с модулем subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

Ребята, я делаю собственную небольшую IDE для питона на питоне, мне надо вызвать компилятор питона, передать туда stdin.

Вот мой код

```
import subprocess as sp
fout = open('test.txt','w')
def call_python(code):
    myStdout = None
    proc = sp.Popen(['python',code],stdout=fout, shell = True)
    print(fout.read())
call_python('да любой код вообщем то')
```

у меня не получается
оно ничего не выводит в файл
помогите

Comment: а разве должно?

Answer (score 0):

Вы создаете объект файла на запись, но не закрываете его, и пытаетесь сразу же прочесть. Вот минимально работающий пример:

```
def call_python(code):
    fout = open('test.txt', 'w')
    sp.Popen(['python', code], stdout=fout, shell=True)
    fout.close()
```

А ещё это можно сделать через [менеджер контекста](https://pythonz.net/references/named/with/):

```
def call_python(code):
    with open('test.txt', 'w') as fout:
        sp.Popen(['python', code], stdout=fout, shell=True)
```

P. S. Замечу, что код переданный таким образом в `python` закончится ошибкой, поскольку `python` ожидает файл скрипта для исполнения. Это можно исправить, если записывать код в файл, и затем, сохранив его, исполнять. Например так:

```
def call_python(code):
    with open('test.py', 'w') as fout:
        fout.write(code)
    sp.Popen(['python', 'test.py'], shell=True)

call_python('print(1+1)')
# 2
```